# Codeigniter force_download fails on large Zip files

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip

When using `force_download` to download a zip file my code works for a zip file that is 268Mb (31 MP3 files) but not for a zip file that is 287Mb (32 MP3 files), the difference being 1 extra MP3 file added to the zip. The download attempts to start and appears as though it keeps starting over and over a couple of times and shows as failed with Chrome indicating that the zip file is incomplete. Windows reports the zip file which is only 61Kb is invalid when trying to open it.

The zip file gets created and MP3 files added to it by another area of code.

I have increased the `memory_limit` up to `1024M` but its no different.

Below is the code I want working:

```
$this->load->helper("download");
$lastbasket = "uniquefilename.zip";
$zipdlpath = base_url()."uploads/zipped/".$lastbasket;
$fileContent = file_get_contents($zipdlpath);
force_download($lastbasket, $fileContent);
```

I have also tried using the following code:

```
$this->load->helper("download");
$lastbasket = "uniquefilename.zip";
$zipdlpath = FCPATH."uploads/zipped/".$lastbasket;
force_download($zipdlpath, NULL);
```

Providing a direct link to the zip file works fine (so I know the issue isnt with the zip file itself) but the force_download function in the controller appears to have an issue with larger files or is there a setting I am missing somewhere that is forcing a limit somehow?

```
PHP 7.1.33
CodeIgniter 3.1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase memory limit by adding this code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with the following custom download helper, may it will work for you.

Ref Link - https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Download-helper-for-large-files

Comment: max_execution_time is set to 600 seconds, the download fails within 10 seconds.

Comment: post_max_size is set to 500M but the code does not post anything so this has no bearing on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

increase memory limit and use fopen, fread

try this

```
$this->load->helper("download");
$lastbasket = "uniquefilename.zip";
$zipdlpath = FCPATH."uploads/zipped/".$lastbasket;
force_download($zipdlpath, NULL);
if (is_file($zipdlpath))
{
    $chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
    $handle = fopen($zipdlpath, 'rb');
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
    exit;
}
```